# Optional downcasting to another type if the first one fails

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-chaining

I have a class with a delegate of type `UIViewController`

This delegate can be one of 2 subclasses of UIViewController. Both subclasses contain a method with the same name taking the same arguments.

```
class TypeOne: UIViewController {
    method() {

    }
}

class TypeTwo: UIViewController {
    method() {

    }
}
```

Currently I'm writing the statement like this and of course it works, but it's driving me batty from  a DRY standpoint.

```
if let delegate = delegate as? TypeOne {
    delegate.method()
} else if let delegate = delegate as? TypeTwo {
    delegate.method()
}
```

I want to do something like

```
if let delegate = delegate as? TypeOne ?? delegate as TypeTwo {
    delegate.method()
}
```

But the above doesn't actually downcast the delegate, as I get an error that type UIViewController doesn't contain 'method'

How else can I chain this so if the first downcast fails, the second one is tried and the delegate is treated as either type rather than a base `UIViewController`?

Comment: @matt Thanks, I tried that, but it does the same - treats delegate as a base UIViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a protocol:

```
protocol MethodHolder {
    func method()
}
class TypeOne: UIViewController, MethodHolder {
    func method() {
    }
}
class TypeTwo: UIViewController, MethodHolder {
    func method() {
    }
}
class ActualViewController : UIViewController {
    var delegate : MethodHolder?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate?.method() // no need to cast anything!
    }
}
```

There is no need to cast anything, because typing the delegate as a MethodHolder guarantees to the compiler (and to you) that this object has a `method` method. Thus you can call that method without bothering to know whether this happens to be a TypeOne or a TypeTwo.

Comment: Thank you very much. Definitely the obvious, and probably cleanest method